# MySQL sum on condition does not work in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL (v5.5), the value of numNotCast, numInFavor is always 0 when selecting all rows of the view. If the select statement is executed alone (not in the view), it works as expected returning the correct count of the the number of rows in the vote column equal to value 'notcast' and 'infavor'.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE
    VIEW `Stats` AS
    select 
        sum(case when `p`.`vote` = 'notcast' then 1 else 0 end) AS `numNotCast`,
        sum(case when `p`.`vote` = 'infavor' then 1 else 0 end) AS `numInFavor`
    from
        (`Debate` `d`
        join `Participant` `p` ON ((`d`.`debateId` = `p`.`debateId`)))
    group by `d`.`debateId`
```

Is this a limitation on MySQL views? How do you accomplish this conditional summing function in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your statement is correct as [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5400/1) confirms, so your problem is probably somewhere else

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Stats AS    
select 
  Debate.debateId,
  sum(case when Participant.vote='notcast' then 1 else 0 end) as numNotCast,
  sum(case when Participant.vote='infavor' then 1 else 0 end) as numInFavor
from
  Debate
inner join 
  Participant on Participant.debateId = Debate.debateId
group by
  Debate.debateId
```

**Updated** after the clarification

Comment: Need to sum on more than one value. I edited the original post to clarify.

Comment: @HandyManDan in that case your solution should work, I created an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5400/1) example to prove

Comment: thanks for creating the fiddle and confirming this works. I resolved this by updating MySQL to latest 5.5.37 (from 5.5.29). I don't see this reported as a bug, but clearly a version related issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are many limitations in MySQL views, but I don't think this is one of them.

I think it is strange that the name of the view is in single quotes.  That might be allowed, but the view may not be doing what you want.  Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `Stats` AS
    select sum(case when `p`.`vote` = 'notcast' then 1 else 0 end) AS `numNotCast`
    from `Debate` `d` join
         `Participant` `p`
         ON `d`.`debateId` = `p`.`debateId`
    group by `d`.`debateId`;
```

By the way, in MySQL, you can simplify the `select` to:

```
select sum(p.vote = 'notcast') as numNotCast
```

Comment: Not the issue, the single quotes were my typo, I corrected.

Comment: Try doing `order by NumNotCast desc` to see if you are missing any rows.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, thanks for the simplified `select` tip